# Problems with custom ScrollBar Delphi

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, vcl, message

I try to implement custom scrollbar painting in standard TMemo. For this I intercepted WM_NCXXX messages and now I can draw buttons and gauge of scrollbar (only vertical, though).
But a day ago I have been stuck with two problems:
1. Where should I do calculations to prepare information for thumb painting? In `WM_NCCALCSIZE`?
2. I can't get how to make necessary calculations to be able to move thumb by mouse as in standard scrollbar?
Information for thumb painting I will get via [GetScrollInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb787583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, it is not so difficult.

At the picture below you can see what I've already done. Left scrollbar is a system scrollbar, right one - custom scrollbar.

[image: control example]

There full code to create control similar on picture.

```
unit MemoEx;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls,
  StrUtils,
  Dialogs,
  ClipBrd;


type
  TMemoEx = class(TCustomMemo)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FVertBar: Boolean;

    FPressedBtn1,
    FPressedBtn2,
    FSelectedBtn1,
    FSelectedBtn2: Boolean;

    FBarBmp,
    FBtn1Bmp,
    FBtn2Bmp: TBitmap;
    MainDC: hDC;

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure WMGETDLGCODE(var Message: TWMGETDLGCODE); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
    procedure WMNCCALCIZE(var Message: TWMNCCALCSIZE); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
    procedure WMNCPAINT(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure WMNCHITTEST(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
    procedure WMNCMOUSEMOVE(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCMOUSEMOVE;
    procedure WMNCLBUTTONDOWN(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure WMNCLBUTTONUP(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCLBUTTONUP;

    procedure Change; override;

    procedure PaintScrollBarVert(DC: hDC);
    procedure PaintButtonVert1(DC: hDC);
    procedure PaintButtonVert2(DC: hDC);
    function CursorPosition(AControl: TControl): TPoint;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

  published
    { new properties }
    property WordWrap;
    property Lines;
    property ScrollBars;
  end;


implementation


constructor TMemoEx.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width := 100;
  Height := 80;
  Constraints.MinWidth := 0;
  Constraints.MinHeight := 0;
  AutoSize := false;
  DoubleBuffered := false;

  FSelectedBtn1 := false;
  FSelectedBtn2 := false;
  FPressedBtn1 := false;
  FPressedBtn2 := false;

  FBarBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FBtn1Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FBtn2Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor TMemoEx.Destroy;
begin
  FBarBmp.Free;
  FBtn1Bmp.Free;
  FBtn2Bmp.Free;

  Inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMGETDLGCODE(var Message: TWMGETDLGCODE);
begin
  Inherited;
  Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB or DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCCALCIZE(var Message: TWMNCCALCSIZE);
begin
  Inherited;

  // decrease width to create non-client area
  Dec(Message.CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Right, 17);
  FVertBar := true;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCPAINT(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;
  MainDC := GetWindowDC(Handle);

  if FVertBar then
    PaintScrollBarVert(MainDC);

  if FVertBar then
  begin
    PaintButtonVert1(MainDC);
    PaintButtonVert2(MainDC);
  end;

  ReleaseDC(Handle, MainDC);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCHITTEST(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCMOUSEMOVE(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;

  // top vert button
  if PtInRect(Rect(Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Top, Width - 2, 17), CursorPosition(Self)) then
    FSelectedBtn1 := true
  else
    FSelectedBtn1 := false;

  // bottom vert button
  if PtInRect(Rect(Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Bottom - 17, Width - 2, ClientRect.Bottom + 17), CursorPosition(Self)) then
    FSelectedBtn2 := true
  else
    FSelectedBtn2 := false;

  Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCLBUTTONDOWN(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;

  // top vert button
  if PtInRect(Rect(Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Top, Width, 17), CursorPosition(Self)) then
    FPressedBtn1 := true;

  // top vert button
  if PtInRect(Rect(Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Bottom - 17, Width, ClientRect.Bottom + 17), CursorPosition(Self)) then
    FPressedBtn2 := true;

  Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMNCLBUTTONUP(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;

  FPressedBtn1 := false;
  FPressedBtn2 := false;
  Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.Change;
begin
  Inherited Changed;
  Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.PaintScrollBarVert(DC: hDC);
begin
  FBarBmp.Width := 17;
  FBarBmp.Height := ClientRect.Bottom;

  FBarBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
  FBarBmp.Canvas.FillRect(FBarBmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
  BitBlt(MainDC, Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Top + 2, FBarBmp.Width, FBarBmp.Height, FBarBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.PaintButtonVert1(DC: hDC);
begin
  FBtn1Bmp.Width := 17;
  FBtn1Bmp.Height := 17;

  if not FSelectedBtn1 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  if FSelectedBtn1 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  if FSelectedBtn1 and FPressedBtn1 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clPurple;

  FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
  BitBlt(DC, Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Top + 2, FBtn1Bmp.Width, FBtn1Bmp.Height, FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.PaintButtonVert2(DC: hDC);
begin
  FBtn2Bmp.Width := 17;
  FBtn2Bmp.Height := 17;

  if not FSelectedBtn2 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  if FSelectedBtn2 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  if FSelectedBtn2 and FPressedBtn2 then
    FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clPurple;

  FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
  BitBlt(DC, Width - 17 - 2, ClientRect.Bottom - 17 + 2, FBtn1Bmp.Width, FBtn1Bmp.Height, FBtn1Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

function TMemoEx.CursorPosition(AControl: TControl): TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(Result);
  Result := AControl.ScreenToClient(Result);
end;


end.
```

P.S.
Top and bottom buttons are interactive)

Thanks anyone for any suggestions!

Comment: Interactive buttons do not interact, is it intentional? I mean, you don't have any scrolling code.

Comment: SertacAkyuz, under 'Interactive' I meant the buttons have Normal state, Hot (when mouse is over one of them) and Pressed state (when mouse is pressed in rect of one button). Of course there no scrolling yet. I can easy add it, but at this time my main problem is creating mechanism of manual (by mouse button, not mouse wheel) scrolling like in standard scrollbar.